# Python/MySQL - Error 1064, can't figure it out

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling

I've been trying to find out what causes the error. I believe it is in the last query to the database. I've marked it with comments.

This error has been giving me a headache for the past 30 minutes.

```
import MySQLdb
import time

# Create a database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="******", user="******", passwd="*****", db="*****")
cur = db.cursor()

# Create a query to select all IDs
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM users")
clientArray = []

# Loop over all IDs returned from query,
# save all IDs in the clientArray
for row in cur.fetchall():
    clientID = str(row[0])
    clientArray.append(clientID)


clientIDInput = ""    
while True:
    # Check and wait for input
    clientIDInput = raw_input("")
    if clientIDInput in clientArray:
        # Check to see whether user is already signed in to the device
        cur.execute("SELECT fitnessStatus FROM users WHERE id=%s", (clientIDInput))
        data = cur.fetchone()
        if data[0] == False:
            cur.execute("UPDATE users SET fitnessStatus='1' WHERE id=%s", (clientIDInput))
            checkInTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            checkOutID = raw_input("")
            if checkOutID == clientIDInput:
                cur.execute("UPDATE users SET fitnessStatus='0' WHERE id=%s", (clientIDInput))
                checkOutTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                print checkInTime
                print checkOutTime

                ### I BELIEVE THIS IS THE CAUSE OF THE ERROR ###
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO activities (id, machinename, checkin, checkout, clientid) VALUES (NULL, Cross Trainer #5, %s, %s, %s)", (checkInTime, checkOutTime, clientIDInput))
                # Send checkInTime and checkOutTime to database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your `INSERT` statement. Try to enclose the string 'Cross Trainer #5' in single quotes:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO activities (id, machinename, checkin, checkout, clientid) VALUES (NULL, 'Cross Trainer #5', %s, %s, %s)", (checkInTime, checkOutTime, clientIDInput))`
```

Luckily, the statement itself is already enclosed in double quotes `"` so that no further change would be required :)

The error 1064 is a bit misleading. It indicates, [amongst others](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064), abuse of a reserved word. And indeed: [`CROSS` is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Thank you. I no longer receive an error! Unfortunately, nothing gets put in to my database... It doesn't return any errors, but it doesn't inject any new stuff in to my activities table. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe missing the `COMMIT WORK` to the connection: `db.commit()` after the respective `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s? The `autocommit` property of the MySQL connection is disabled by default afaik.